# Why can't template type arguments be implicitly casted?

Tags: c++, templates, types, type-conversion

Given this code:

```
template<typename T>
struct Type
{
    T value;
};

template<typename T>
Type<T> operator+(const Type<T>& type, T val)
{
    Type<T> type;
    type.value += val;
    return type;
}

int main()
{
    Type<float> type;
    type = type + 2;
}
```

I get the error in MSVC:

```
Error C2782 'Type<T> operator +(const Type<T> &,T)': template parameter 'T' is ambiguous

Error C2676 binary '+': 'Type<float>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator 

Error no operator "+" matches these operands
```

I would assume that it would simply promote the int to a float, but apparently it doesn't want to do that. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: You can create a nondeduced context: `template<class T> struct ndc { using type = T; }; template<class T> using nondeduced = typename ndc<T>::type;` then `template<class T> Type<T> operator+(const Type<T>& type, nondeduced<T> val);`

Comment: Alternatively, why don't you postpone the type conversion? Just use another template parameter `U` for the second function argument and let the conversion happen within `type.value += val;`

Comment: Oh, and the problem with your code is that the template parameter is deduced independently from each function argument, so the compiler deduces `T == float` for the first argument but `T == int` for the second argument. This mismatch is an error, reported by MSVC as "template parameter 'T' is ambiguous".

Comment: The msvc error message is useless: gcc gives `error: declaration of ‘Type<T> type’ shadows a parameter Type<T> type;` and after fixing that `error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘Type<float>’ and ‘int’)` followed by clarifying notes

Comment: @dyp The placeholder text for comments reads "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." Please don't put answers in comments. I had wanted to put more in my actual answer, posted as an answer, but it's already covered by your comments. And including it in my answer anyway, even if I use my own words and come up with the idea independently, would just lead me to being falsely accused of plagiarism again.

Comment: @hvd Do it. Just do it! ;) I thought this is a dupe anyway, comments are for me a way to give hints quickly, without taking time to write up an answer (I'm quite slow at writing answers) or searching for dups. And yeah, I know that's not the purpose of comments.

Comment: @dyp Thanks. I can understand why you do it. I actually think that even if you put the exact words that you put in comments in answers, they would already be acceptable as answers, though. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler cannot determine that in `Type<float> + int`, you want to call `operator+<float>` (forcing a conversion from `int` to `float`) rather than `operator+<int>` (forcing a conversion from `Type<float>` to `Type<int>`). Sure, that second interpretation would lead to an error, but the ambiguity is detected and reported at that point already.

In this specific case, you probably want `Type<T> + U` to always return `Type<T>`. In that case, you need to make sure that the compiler will not be able to determine a `Type<U>` to convert to, regardless of whether the conversion is supported.

@dyp posted in the comment section how you can achieve this using a helper template. Aside from different names, this is basically:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity { typedef T type; };
template <typename T>
Type<T> operator+(const Type<T>& type, typename identity<T>::type val) { ... }
```

The reason this works is because the compiler cannot and isn't allowed to figure out which `T` to use to make `identity<T>::type` is `int`: you could have some specialisation of `identity` somewhere that also makes `identity<haha>::type` `int`. As a result, only `type` is used for determining `T`.

It works, but in this particular case, a simpler approach in my opinion is to make `operator+` a member function. The hidden `this` argument in member functions already doesn't get converted to other types.

```
template<typename T>
struct Type
{
    T value;
    Type operator+(T val) { ... }
};
```

---

Note: if you want to support `T + Type<T>` additions as well, then you cannot use this exact same approach: you cannot use a member function for that. But if you already have this one operator as a member function, and if addition is commutative, you can use a non-member `operator+` for the opposite conversion that just swaps the operands. @dyp already pointed out an alternative approach using two template arguments, and that works well if combined with the swap here:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto operator+(T val, const Type<U>& type) -> decltype(type.operator+(val)) {
  return type.operator+(val);
}
```

Now, if you write `int + Type<float>`, `operator+<int, float>` gets instantiated and called, which then ends up calling `Type<float>.operator+(float)`. So `val` still gets converted to `float`.

(The reason for writing `type.operator+(val)` rather than `type + val` is because otherwise an invalid addition of `Type<T> + Type<U>` gets swapped to `Type<U> + Type<T>`, which gets swapped back to `Type<T> + Type<U>` again, until the compiler reaches its internal limits and may even crash.)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not have direct recquirements on how to use operators between User types and standard types: Type is a user type.

```
Type<float> + int has no standard rules defined on the priority of casts.
```

Should it promote *val* int to float or type Type to something else.
The compiler does not know Type

To solve this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
Type<T> operator+(const Type<T>& type, U val)
{
    // Type<T> type; also do not ovewrite the parameter
    type.value += val; // here it knows that type.value is float
                       // standard rules for float + int
    return type;
}
```

To give you an example why it is too complicated for the compiler to decide what to promote to what, your Type could have been:

```
template<typename T>
struct Type
{
    T key;
    int value;
};

template<typename T>
Type<T> operator+(const Type<T>& type, T val)
{
    type.value += val;
    return type;
}
```

Without analysing both the definition of the Type and the implementation of operator+ the compiler does not know what you expect, and to do this analysis is very complicatid.